# exposing dynamic schemas with graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

My application handles schema on the fly. Users can upload new domains or change the definitions of existing domains. For ex, say, I ship the product with a user schema like this :

```
user { 
  fn, ln, age
}
Later user can change this definition to include new properties;
user { 
  fn, ln, age, 
  salary, address
}
```

or they can add an entirely new domain concept.

If I use GraphQL, is there a way to change the schema dynamically ?

Another question is; 
Our schemas have conditions that make some parts of the schema relevant. For ex;
the user schema may have something like this:

```
user {
  fn, ln, age, gender
  foo (if gender == Male)
  bar (if gender == Female)
}
```

are there provisions in GraphQL to express these. I am ok to handle it in java code, but, then the schema look ups need to be routed to my code rather than referring to a static schema registry.

Answer (score 2):

I had to solve the same kind of problem: I have a graphQL java server which can load plugins dynamically (each plugins come with its own schema definition).

You have to implement your own `GraphQLSchemaProvider`and override `public GraphQLSchema getSchema(HttpServletRequest request)`. Then load / reload your schema according to refresh time / request condition (ie: user) / anything else...

For your second question, you can use Inline fragment http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#inline-fragments