# Is it possible to change a GraphQL schema at runtime and write resolvers that handle this dynamic schema? (in Java)

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am working with GraphQL (in Java) and I would like to find a way to do the following:
I need the possibility to constantly adapt the GraphQL schema at runtime without restart. In particular I need to be able to add new fields to GraphQL types. Moreover I need the possibility to be able to write resolvers which can handle this dynamic schema.

I do not have example code yet, so just think of the simplest example (one GraphQL type with several fields that can all be of different type).

My problem is that I am quite new in GraphQL and I do not have a lot of experience with it. Of course I looked for a solution on the internet, but I did not find one yet (or just did not notice that I found it due to my lacking experience with GraphQL).
The only interesting discovery I made is this: [exposing dynamic schemas with graphql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994102/exposing-dynamic-schemas-with-graphql) . But I do not understand how this solution works because 1) I do not know how to reload the schema at runtime and 2) I do not know how to write the resolvers so that they can handle that dynamic schema.

So can anybody help me with my problem and/or can answer my questions regarding the link I found?

I am very thankful for every help, no matter how extensive it is. Like I told before, I am quite new in GraphQL. Therefore I would be also very thankful for links to examples (if possible), so that I can understand better.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: While there are use cases where dynamically changing the schema might be valid (e.g. building a headless CMS) this sounds like a red flag to me. Generally, a GraphQL schema should not change. A GraphQL schema is a contract between to pieces of software and it is essential that it stays the same over time. Therefore most server libraries are not made for changing the schema at runtime, especially not the ones for statically typed, compiled languages. One could probably hack something together in Node.js...

Answer (score 0):

@userongithub0 you may take a look at GraphQL [Schema Directives](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v16/sdl-directives/)
And specifically on the [rest directive](https://github.com/graphql-community/graphql-directive-rest)

Answer (score -3):

First of all, don't ever try to do that or use only if there're some very strict situations. Here's why:

- A schema is like a contract between the `front-end` & `backend` & on change, it can lead to **instability** between both of them very quickly.
- If you try to change the schema of `GraphQL`, it might **fail** to connect properly with your resolvers & consecutively with your database as well.
- Whenever there's is a change in the schema the GraphQL server (the server handler, in general) needs to be restarted (recompile) & it will take time, hence results in high response time.

No matter what language you are using, you should always see it as a red flag. In my opinion, it will be a really bad practice.

Comment: This is an opinion, rather than answering the question. There are many use cases where changing the schema at runtime is a sensible approach, particularly given GraphQL's inbuilt introspection system (which is designed to allow clients discover the schema) so it is best to keep such opinions to a different forum